# How to convert jquery ajax call to WinJS.xhr or Win8 equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, winjs

I have a question regarding porting iOS/Android app to Win8.  I am currently using a modified version of http://srobbin.github.com/jquery-pageslide/ pageslide with an ajax call to load a menu.html page on the side.  The AJAX call looks like the following...

```
    $.ajax({
    url: $str,
    dataType: "text", 
    success: function(data) {         
        $("#menu").html(data);

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
});
```

In Win8, I am receiving this error..

```
    Exception was thrown at line 8490, column 29 in ms-appx://664ace5f-4774-4928-bc94-ad4650a1ede1/js/jquery-1.8.2.js
0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.
```

This is where it breaks in the jQuery code.

```
    if (s.username) {
                        xhr.open(s.type, s.url, s.async, s.username, s.password);
                    } else {
                        xhr.open(s.type, s.url, s.async); //<-------------------
                    }
```

I have done some research and it appears that windows 8 will not allow local ajax calls.  How can I convert this to a WinJS.xhr call or something that will work on Win8?

**EDIT - After first answer.**

What I'm looking to do is go to $str (which is the url of the file with the html for the menu, ie menu.html) and populate $('#menu') with it via a html call.  What do I put in the XHR return to get the text from my menu.html and then on the success call I can assign it to the file.

My first time messing with XHR/AJAX so please forgive any ignorance.

**EDIT #2**

I have redone the jquery call to using the WinJS.xhr... as in the following code.

```
    WinJS.xhr({
        type: "GET",
        url: $str,
        responseType: "text",

    }).then(function(success){
        console.log(success);
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);    
    }
    );
```

This still returns an access is denied exception.  On this piece of base java code..

```
req.open(
                    options.type || "GET",
                    options.url,
                    // Promise based XHR does not support sync.
                    //
                    true,
                    options.user,
                    options.password
                );
```

The exception is documented here.

```
SCRIPT5: Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 2332, column 21 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/base.js
0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.
```

If the file name/path ($str) is altered to an incorrect path then I get a resource_not_found error, which is self explanatory.  I am not sure what to try now.  Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Did you add your destination URL to the list of allowed end points in the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that the URL that you're hitting is "local". Is it a separate service on the machine or is it another file in the same project?
If it's the former then actually it should still work while you're developing, but it will be disallowed in production. The certification process won't allow apps to make requests to localhost.
I suspect the latter. In that case you definitely *should* be able to request it with xhr. Look at my codeSHOW project ([link](http://aka.ms/codeshowapp)) at the Fragments and Pages demo. Also see the WinJS.xhr demo.

EDIT - just want to include the answer as well. (Great App!!)

This replaces the $.ajax call in jquery.

```
        WinJS.xhr({
        url: '/menu.html',
        responseType: "document",

    }).then(function(xhr){

        var temp = xhr.response.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
        $('#menu').html(temp);
    }

    );
```

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified, it is within the same project.  Basically I have a set of HTML files that share the same menu file that contains the HTML to populate the menu.  All of these files including the HTML file are within the same directory.  Checking out your demo now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the xhr callback and return your own xhr. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: $str,
    xhr: function(){
        return yourDesiredXHRHere;
    },
    dataType: "text", 
    success: function(data) {         
        $("#menu").html(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your response was good, in that it enlightened me on how things are supposed to work.  But I updated my question to reflect what function I'm supposed to call to get the data back from my url file?

Comment: I was under the impression you knew what xhr object you needed to use, I don't know which one (if there is one) would allow local ajax requests in IE10.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I'm researching that now.  I appreciate the insight though.  Thanks!

Comment: Kevin, I added some more detail if you wouldn't mind taking a look and see if anything jumps out at you.  Thanks for your time I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have anything new to add. It may just be that IE10 properly prevents local ajax requests from being successful due to security restrictions. Google Chrome has that same restriction.